# How to get a navbar menu to show itself from a side on top of the existing page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default, Bootstrap lets you hide/show a navbar menu from the top. I'd like to implement it in such a way that it opens from a side. I've taken a look at [sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) and many other code examples but they all have one flaw- the menu pushes the existing content to a side to reveal itself. The page of [GDG Bengaluru](http://gdgbangalore.in/) however has a menu that comes on top of the existing content rather than pushing it aside. How do you do this? Is there any plugin or jQuery hack that lets us do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can check with the below link. Let me know if you got what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6JnT/16/

```
 $('button').click(function () {
    $(".panel").animate({
        left: '0px'
    });


    $('.panel').animate({width:'toggle'},800);

});
```

Here is the perfect link what you wanted.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6JnT/18/

Comment: Yes!! I've updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e6JnT/17/) to show that it doesn't push the existing content.

Comment: The first time I click on the button, the div appears and vanishes. Later it's fine. Any idea why?

Comment: But how do you integrate this with the navbar to ensure that this behaviour is only on smaller devices?

Comment: @praroh1 Here is the updated answer just as you wanted. Please do check it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a popular Bootstrap fork - Jasny Bootstrap (slide-in, push, reveal).
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas

**OR**

You can use already working demo.

http://jsbin.com/OjOTIGaP/1/edit

https://jsbin.com/seqola/2/edit

Comment: The examples have the same issue that I've mentioned in my question. The menu pushes the existing content to the right. It isn't appearing on top of it.